# How do I hold a specific position using Zaber Console Script?

Tags: console, zaber

I am trying to write a simple script using Zaber Console.
I basically have to move my robot arm to a certain position (i.e. 43.9mm) hold the position for 10 minutes and go back to the home position.

I found all the command for moving (fast/slow and with a certain acceleration) but I can't undestand how to tell the machine to stay at 43.9mm poistion for 10 minutes.

Any suggestions ?
I am coding in "this language":

```
if(PortFacade.Port.IsAsciiMode)
{
    Conversation.Request("move abs", 881890);
    Conversation.PollUntilIdle();
}
else
{
    Conversation.Request(Command.MoveAbsolute, 881890);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Riccardo

Answer (score 0):

For your reference, if you are coding through the script editor in Zaber Console, we offer a scripting page which covers C#, Javascript, VP, as well as Python. You can find the scripting page here: http://www.zaber.com/wiki/Software/Zaber_Console/Scripting

The language in your script is using C#, and a quick program to execute what you'd like to do can be written like this:

```
#template(simple)
var device1 = PortFacade.GetConversation(1); // This is assuming your device
// is device 1 in the chain. 
// The device list in Zaber Console will let you know the device number.
// Alternatively, you can use the renumber command to change the device number.


device1.Request("move abs 100000"); //the data value for 43.9 mm will vary 
// from device to device. The formula would be 43.9[mm]/ Microstep size[mm] = Data value
// The microstep size can be found on the product page at www.Zaber.com, or 
// email Contact@Zaber.com
Sleep(5000); //Sleep is in milliseconds
device1.Request("move abs 0");
```

If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to email Contact@Zaber.com.

Regards,

Albert

Comment: Dear Albert, thanks a lot. I think I should take advantage of your kindness and share my "script" text cause I bet you could summerize it. I'll try the email you gave me. Cause I used the examples within zaber console to extrapolate my script, but i am sure it could be done much better.